# OPENSSL AES_ecb_encrypt encryption decryption algorithm, on windows systems need to pay attention to anything?

Tags: c++, ssl, aes

openssl AES_ecb_encrypt encryption decryption algorithm, what do you need to pay attention to on windows systems?  Because I have a problem now, the data and files of the encryption and decryption interface I wrote are normal. Encrypted data obtained through web page encryption tools cannot be decrypted in the code
I think the key and the alignment are the same way,And the encryption mode is to use ECB.

```
std::string DecodeAES(std::string szData)
{

std::string szDst;

try
{

    if (szData.empty())
    {
       return "";
    }
const unsigned int uKeySize = static_cast<unsigned int>(m_szAesRecvKey.size());

    AES_KEY key = { 0 };
    AES_set_decrypt_key(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(m_szAesRecvKey.data()), static_cast<int>(8 *   uKeySize), &key);
    std::vector<unsigned char> sRst(szData.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < szData.size(); i += AES_BLOCK_SIZE)
    {
        AES_ecb_encrypt(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(szData.data() + i), &sRst[i], &key, AES_DECRYPT);
    }
    const size_t pads = sRst[sRst.size() - 1];
    if (pads > 0 && pads <= uKeySize && ((sRst.size() - pads) > 0))
    {
        szDst.assign(sRst.begin(), sRst.end() - pads);
    }

}
catch (const std::exception)
{
}
return szDst;

}
```

Plaintext -> aes , plaintext ->  aes ->   base64  , All of them tried and failed.

So it is possible that Windows and web tools (other languages java, py) encryption and decryption of ciphertext data there are any precautions.

Comment: Works on my (Windows) machine. The problem is rather with your data. They are probably either corrupted or incompatible with the code. Post non-productive test data. Also, it is less error-prone to use the high level APIs (EVP functions, s. [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption)) rather than the low level ones.

Comment: OT: swallowing exceptions is a good way to give yourself more work by hiding vital clues. Either log the exception or let it propagate.